# Kotlin null checks during nullable WeakHashMap iteration

Tags: kotlin

```
// I know activity is not ideal here due to lack of equality guaranty; please ignore this part
private val mActivities: WeakHashMap<Activity, Int> = WeakHashMap()
....
mActivities.put(null, null)
mActivities.filter { (backStackEntry: Activity?) ->
    // Issue: this does not show any errors but fails at runtime
    Logger.warn("$TAG - Activity ${backStackEntry.localClassName}")
    val entry: Activity? = backStackEntry
    // Works as expected: this does show the error as expected
    Logger.warn("$TAG - Activity ${entry.localClassName}")
}
```

Kotlin null safety checks are not working when I try to iterate through WeakHashMap which can contain null values. Examples listed above. Any ideas as to why this is happening will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Clarification**
`${backStackEntry?.localClassName}` works, but my concern is around why Android Studio or build logic is not showing a static check error or compile error for `${backStackEntry.localClassName}`. But with `${entry.localClassName}`, Android Studio flags this as an error.

Comment: try this: `${backStackEntry?.localClassName}`

Comment: Thanks for the time - ```${backStackEntry?.localClassName}``` works, but my concern is around why Android Studio or build logic is not showing a static check error or compile error for ```${backStackEntry.localClassName}```. But with ```${entry.localClassName}```, Android Studio flags this as an error.

Answer (score 1):

`WeakHashMap<Activity, Int>` type doesn't provide information about its content nullability.

Consider replacing `private val mActivities: WeakHashMap<Activity, Int> = WeakHashMap()` with `private val mActivities: MutableMap<Activity?, Int?> = WeakHashMap()`.

Since you explicitly specify `backStackEntry` nullability and the compiler still doesn't flag `backStackEntry` dereferencing as an error, it must be a bug, and you should report it on [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).